# Google Apps feed Google API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-apps

I am uploading data to Google apps programmatically. I am using the following code

```
MailItemEntry[] entries = new MailItemEntry[1];
entries[0] = new MailItemEntry();
entries[0].BatchData = new Google.GData.Client.GDataBatchEntryData();
MailItemFeed feed = mailItemService.Batch(domain, UserName, entries);
```

Is there any way to find out how much data(in MB or GB) has been uploaded to google apps.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just to clarify do you mean in that `.Batch()` or in the entire account?

Comment: Google Data API are restful, could you get the payload size from the GET or POST?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do it utilize the `BatchAsync` of the `mailItemService` and hook up to the `AsyncOperationProgress` event. This will tell you, as a percent, how much of the data has been sent. Just be aware that `BatchAsync` is a non blocking call, so your application will need to change as a result.

If you have access to the length of the data that you are sending, you can calculate how much has gone up with each progress changed event.

See Google-docs
http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r902/docs/folder4/AllMembers_T_Google_GData_Apps_Migration_MailItemService.htm

MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs.aspx

Hope that helps